# How to delete selected/highlighted string from NSSearchField? (Swift)

Tags: swift

I am trying to remove the selected/highlighted string from a search field.

[image]

In the attached picture, I am trying to remove the word deleted. So far, this is my progress:

```
if let selectedTextStartIndex = searchField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange.lowerBound, 
   let selectedTextLength = searchField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange.length, 
   let selectedTextRange = searchField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange{
   if let selectedText = searchField.currentEditor(with: selectedTextRange){
       print(selectedText)              //deleted
       print(selectedTextStartIndex)    //15
       print(selectedTextRange)         //7
   }
}

extension String {
    func substring(with nsrange: NSRange) -> Substring? {
        guard let range = Range(nsrange, in: self) else { return nil }
        return self[range]
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to proceed with this. Also, is there a simpler way to do this?
I am looking for a code that can be reused on any other string as well.

Edit:

[image]

In this case, I want to remove the first deleted only.

Comment: Why not just do: `if let selectedRange = searchField.currentEditor().selectedRange { searchField.currentEditor().text = searchField.currentEditor().replaceSubrange(selectedRange, with: "") }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `removeSubrange` method that would work well here:

```
if let string = searchField?.currentEditor()?.string,
   let range = searchField?.currentEditor()?.selectedRange,
   let strRange = Range<String.Index>(range, in: string)
{
    searchField?.currentEditor()?.string.removeSubrange(strRange)
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you :)